# Uniform convergence of infinite product of holomorphic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

I think the following statement is true but I'm not completely sure.

> Let $\Omega$ be an open set of the complex plane and let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions defined on $\Omega.$ If the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |1-f_n|$$
>   converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega,$
>   then the infinite product
>   $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n$$
>   converges absolutely on $\Omega,$ uniformly on compact subsets, and the function $f$ it defines on $\Omega$ is holomorphic. In particular $f(z) = 0$ if and only if $f_n(z) = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Rhis is true. Check Lemma 7.5.8 from Conway's Functions onf One Complex Variable, 2nd Ed.

Comment: Thank you very much.